# Can we model visibility between two points in a 3D space using a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks

Consider a 3D space that contains many opaque objects which can obscure vision from one point in the space to another. Suppose I have a sampling of points in the space, and also a sampling of which points are visible from one another. Is there a way to build a model $f$ that takes in two points $A$ and $B$, such that $f(A,B) = f(B,A)$? Is this something we could build a neural network for? Or could this better be solved with an unsupervised approach?

Answer (score 1):

f is a discontious funtion, which is difficult for a neural network to learn.
You can learn a signed distance function, and test whether it's reachable from A to B to decide visibility.